# Textfield autocomplete doesn't have a validation and error message - Oracle Apex v21.1

Tags: javascript, oracle, validation, plsql, oracle-apex

I was trying to replace a Textfield with a Textfield with autocomplete on a form, which would display the name of existing articles in the list to help the user.

Unfortunately, the textfield with autocomplete doesn't have a validation incase it's NULL or empty, even tough the **Value required** is set to TRUE in the Attributes.

Here's the difference between the Textfield with and without autocomplete if I'm trying to insert an article with an empty name

**Basic textfield, without autocomplete, all validations are shown :**
[image: basic textfield]

---

**Textfield with autocomplete, the validation for the said field is not displayed :**
[image: textfield with autocomplete]

---

**However, when ALL the others fields are not empty, thus no errors are displayed and I try to submit, the validation for the textfield with autocomplete DOES appear, why ? :**
[image: textfield with autocomplete with validation]

What could be the reasons for this ? Is there a way to display the error message with all the others ? Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Thomas what version of Apex are you on ?

Comment: Hello, I'm on v21.1.0

Comment: Tested on 22.1 (apex.oracle.com) with a text field AND text field with autocomplete. Both have "value required" set to "Y". When I submit with empty fields I get error messages for both items. I wonder if the page item type "Text Field with autocompleted" has changed between versions. I suggest testing it on 22.1 yourself. As a workaround you can create validations (instead of using the "value required" attribute ) on each of the items to ensure the behaviour on submit is similar.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the "Value required" attribute on all of them and set a validation for each of them with the same text, I hope it will not mess anything up in the future. I'm not sure how to upgrade my Oracle Apex environnment to 22.1, is it risky for my application and/or will it affect it's components, the functionality, etc ?

Comment: This will most probably not mess up anything in the future, they're just validations that functionality will not change. Upgrading every release (6 monthly) or every 2 releases should go really smoothly. You'll have to check your apps of course, but functionality should not break. There is a much higher risk of upgrade issues if you wait longer. Upgrade issues are: deprecated api's or components (those are documented in the release notes), changed js libraries (this can affect custom javascript code)

Comment: I was indeed worried about the effect it can have on my custom javascript code since I have some on my application, I'll check with my DBA for a possible upgrade if we find it necessary. Thanks again for your help on the validation. You can post an answer if you want me to validate it ! :-)